# how to create materialized view to connect two different oracle database tables

Tags: oracle, ddl, materialized-views

i need to create a mview to get the data from the remote database to destination database using refresh command.

this is my sql query to create mview:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK SI_DB
    CONNECT TO SYSTEM IDENTIFIED BY password
    USING 'SI_DEV';
```

this is my tns.ora file:

```
SI_DEV=
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = servidor)(PORT = 1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SID = MSQL)
)
(HS=OK)
)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

I don't know how to create a mview for remote target.

Do we need to put our destination or remote database into the .or file?

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Use `service_name instead` of `sid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tnsnames.ora` on the server where you create the DBLink needs to contain the connect information to the remote Oracle instance. You can also create a DBLink without changing `tnsnames.ora` on that server by providing the connection descriptor when creating the dblink:

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK SI_DB
  CONNECT TO some_user
  IDENTIFIED BY some_password
USING '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = servidor)(PORT = 1521)) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = MSQL) ) (HS=OK))';
```

Note that creating a DBLink with the `system` user to enable materialized views to a regular user is a bad idea.

Once you have the DBLink you can create the mview using:

```
create materialize view foobar
as
select *
from the_table@si_db;
```

Note that `the_table` references a table in the schema of the user that is specified in the DBLink. That's one of the reasons you should not use the `system` account for the DBLink. If the table is not in the schema of the DBLink's user, you need to qualify the table name:

```
create materialize view foobar
as
select *
from the_user.the_table@si_db;
```